# Gravity forms jQuery variable to PHP variable populate dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I would like to pass a jQuery variable to php variable, in purpose to make a database selection. Im using gravity forms for the process, the jQuery code get the data from the drop down(2) and add it to another field(5), but i need the selected data from the dropdown to use in database selection:

> SELECT Title FROM table WHERE Status=**$variable**

and the selected value to add to the field 5 in gravity forms.

---

```
    add_filter("gform_pre_render_1", "monitor_dropdown");
    function monitor_dropdown($form){

        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){

                jQuery('#input_1_2').bind('change', function()
                {
                    //get selected value from drop down;
                    var selectedValue = jQuery("#input_1_2").val();
        $.post("hold.php", {"data": selectedValue}, function (txt) {
    alert(txt);
});
                    //populate a text field with the selected drop down value
                    //jQuery("#input_1_5").val(selectedValue);
                });
            });
            </script>

        <?php
        return $form;
        }
```

**hold.php**

```
    add_filter( 'gform_field_value_url_data', 'populate_date' );
    function populate_date( $value) {
    $value2 = $_POST['data'];
    return $value2 ;
       }
// OR
       $value3 = $_POST['data'];
       return $value3;
```

***Even after adding the ajax im not still what i need, is the ajax right? Or where im wrong ?***

Comment: You need to use `$.ajax`

Comment: I agree with @Hackerman, you'd need to use some ajax in your code snippet and post your input change value to an external PHP file that would do something with the data you send to it. In that file you could include your database query and return its results to do something with if you needed to.

Comment: @Hackerman i added ajax but still no success !!!

Answer (score -1):

You can handle the **Form** submission in the `$POST` macro variable.

Your **Form** must look like this :

```
<form action="link_to_your_php" method="post">
    <input id="input_1_5" name="input_1_5" />
    <input type="submit" value="Find" />
</form>
```

Then you can handle the variable like this.

```
<?php
    $variable = $POST['input_1_5'];
?>
```

And then make your query

```
SELECT Title FROM table WHERE Status=$variable
```

Comment: I need to pass the variable before the submission not after. And for the fom im using gravity form

Comment: Please don't dump variables in queries like it's okay, because [it's not](http://bobby-tables.com/).